# get the value of the current ID in an list item

Tags: java, javascript, dom, html-lists, getelementbyid

can any of you pls tell me how to get the value of the current ID out of this list item.
I have many list items which are generated by java servlets so I need to get the current ID of the list (which is clicked):

so when i click:

```
$('li.doBlokkeer').hover(function(e) {
```

now I need the value of the id

```
<li class="doBlokkeer" id="${cell.id}"></li>
```

I think it is something like, but it doesnt work

```
  var idblokkeer = document.getElementById('doBlokkeer');
  var valueid = idblokkeer.getAttribute('id');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to get with using `this`

```
$('li.doBlokkeer').hover(function (e) {
    alert($(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Where `this`  is the current element you hovered.

http://learn.jquery.com/javascript-101/this-keyword/

[**Have a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/sureshbm13/fRUUd/1571/)

Answer (score -1):

Change this -

```
var idblokkeer = document.getElementById('doBlokkeer');
  var valueid = idblokkeer.getAttribute('id');
```

to this-

```
var idblokkeer = document.getElementsByClassName[0]('doBlokkeer');
  var valueid = idblokkeer.getAttribute('id');
```